# HTML Text before and after (Prefix/Suffix) Input field

Tags: html, input

I need to do have in HTML text show up before and after an input field, on the same line. The prefix and suffix are added at run time, and may or may not be there. I have tried  and  and combinations there of. Here is what I have now:

[image]

Here is what I am trying to achieve (remembering that the values will sometimes not be there, so I would like the text input recover that space when they are not there:

[image]

Here is my current code (I did cut out some class defs to make it more readable):

```
<div>
    <div>Prefix and Suffix</div>
    <div class="row">
        <span style="display:inline-block">Test<input type="text" class="input">Dollars</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would prefer a solution that does not use tables (just div) but if that is the only way to do it, so be it.

Comment: Pasting that html into JSBin and JSFiddle both gave what you were after.... I am guessing there is some css/styling we are not seeing that is causing this behavior? If I set the width of the input to 100%, it looks like what you have now. If I just remove width styling, it looks like what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I did remove some styling to make the code clearer. I will take a look at that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using flex seems to work just fine for me. Might be worth a try.

```
   <div style="display:flex;">
       <div>Test&nbsp;</div>
       <input type="text">
       <div>&nbsp;Dollars</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it try. Removing some styles got it all on the same line, but I need the Prefix to the left, the Suffix to the right, and the input to fill in the rest of the space.

Comment: Perfect solution! Filled in needed space for the Input. Also works when either Prefix or Suffix is missing. Only had to add "align-item:center" and some margins.